# Does my program need to have an exception in Windows firewall?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-firewall

My program uses a component which makes `http` connections over the internet, but when I install and run my program on a clean installation of XP, it runs fine without an exception in the Windows Firewall having to be made.  Why doesn't it need an exception in the firewall?

Answer (score 0):

If it makes only http connections, those are allowed to enable browsers accessing the Internet.

In general firewall rules can be based on various conditions, one of which is the port (http is port 80), other could be the protocol (http is TCP) and the program itself.  In order to enhance user experience and allow any browsers to work correctly without extra configuration, TCP connections to port 80 are configured to be allowed.

Comment: So if your application only uses port 80 you can pretty much do whatever you want?  Isn't that a security risk for the OS?

Comment: It depends.  First of all, the OS has (should have) other safeguards as well.  Second you probably heard about browser security bugs.  So the answer is that the OS cannot know what exactly the app is doing, but can have some safeguards (one of these safeguards is disallowing communications on random ports unless explicitly allowed).  On the other hand on an OS like Windows, you would like as much to work "out-of-the-box" as you can (for the convenience of many security untrained users) without opening the OS to too much risk.  Port 80 supposed to be a webserver serving up web pages.  [cont.]

Comment: [cont] The OS cannot know what exactly is going on on that far-away IP, but it is usually a safe bet that it is a webserver on port 80.  Of course - as you guessed - this is inexact and you can have things like proxies that provide a different protocol on port 80 to get around the limiation that some other ports are not allowed.  Properly configuring a firewall that can detect things like this is not something you can do out-of-the-box, and most user would not know either.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Firewall only protects you against incoming connections; all outgoing and local connection are automatically permitted. This means that it is not as secure as a full software firewall, but it avoids nagging you every time Firefox auto-updates itself.